# attempt method doesn't work, laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I am using a database with a table called "usuario" instead of "user", I have managed to register users, however, when I try to login and pass the parameters to the attempt function, for some reason doesn't create the session, I made changes to the auth.php files and also added the name of the table in my model, what may be wrong?

this is my current code

```
public function login(Request $data)
{


    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $data->email, 'clave' => $data->password])) {
        // Authentication passed...
        return "success";
        //return redirect()->intended('dashboard');
    }else{
        return "error";
    }
}
```

should I change something else inside the internal functions of laravel to be able to authenticate with other fields?

Answer (score 0):

I wish i can comment. LOL 
First, ensure you run the following command to enable/activate authentication in Laravel 
 `php artisan make:auth` 
Since you're not using the user table, add the following to you user model to make use of your table 
`public $table = "usuario";` 
Check your config/auth.php also and run the script again.